# Group structure on set of homotopy classes

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, functors

Let $\text{Top}_*$ be the category of *pointed topological spaces*, and fix some $(X,x)\in\text{Top}_*$. Suppose that for all $Y\in\text{Top}_*$ we can give a group structure to the set $[X,Y]$ of homotopy classes of maps fixing the base point, in such a way that there exists a functor
$$
\mathcal F:\text{Top}_*\to\text{Gr},\;
(Y,y)\mapsto[(X,x),(Y,y)]
$$
where $\text{Gr}$ is the category of groups.

> Is it true that the identity of $[(X,x),(Y,y)]$ is the class of the constant map?

If the functor $\mathcal F$ happens to be the most natural one, i.e., the one given by composition: for a continuous map $f:Y\to Z$,

$$\mathcal F(f):[X,Y]\to[X,Z],\quad[h]\mapsto[f\circ h],$$
then this is easily seen to be true. This is, for example, what happens for the fundamental group. However, what if $\mathcal F$ is an arbitrary functor (assuming, of course, that a functor not of this form exists, which for all I know it might not at all)? Is it possible that the identity of group is not the constant map?

Comment: $\textbf{Top}_*$ and $\textbf{Grp}$ both have zero objects, and your functor is guaranteed to preserve zero objects. Thus the functor also preserves zero morphisms. That tells you what the identity element of your groups must be.

Comment: FWIW I don't think it need be true.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I have not fully read the question. This answer presumes that the functor lifts the normal Hom functor on both objects and morphisms.

Clearly the identity element of $[X,*]$ is constant. The image of the identity of a group under a group homomorphism is the identity of the codomain. Since, $*$ is initial and the composition of any constant map with another map is constant, we conclude that all identities are represented by constant.

Comment: I see I posted at the same time as Zhen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I still don't see how this proves it. Certainly $[X,*]$ is the trivial group and the identity is the class of the constant map, and I also see that $i:\{*\}\to Y$ induces a map $\mathcal F(i):[X,*]\to[X,Y]$ which maps the identity to the identity. Hence $\mathcal F(i)([\text{constant map}])$ is the identity of $[X,Y]$, but why is $\mathcal F(i)([\text{constant map}])$ the class of a constant map?

Comment: @user3141592 Under $F(i)$ the identity of the group $[X,*]$ goes to the identity of the group $[X,Y]$. The identity in $[X,*]$ is the constant map. $F(i)$ on maps is post composition with $i$. This post composition on the constant map $X \rightarrow *$ yields the constant map $X \rightarrow Y$. Hence, the constant map $X \rightarrow Y$ is the identity.

Comment: Why does $\mathcal F(i)$ act like "post composition" though? Maybe I didn't explain myself clearly enough, but in the question $\mathcal F$ is *any* functor, I am not assuming anything about how it acts on functions

Comment: @user3141592 Oh I'm sorry, it looks like I skipped reading that part of your question. My brain is getting a bit confused while thinking about this, so if I think of an answer I will let you know. I suspect the answer is no, and I think my and Zhen's responses rely on using the normal action on maps. To me the first question to answer is if its possible to even supply a functor which acts on objects like Hom but doesn't act like that on maps.

Comment: Probably I should've highlighted that part to avoid misunderstandings, sorry :) Thanks a lot for your time!